# Magento2 : How to add Edit link also existing shipping address in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

How to add Edit link also existing shipping address in checkout page in Magneto 2?

How to update the selected address data when i click the  radio button of the shipping address.

I was saw the my console process:

```
**Default working process Edit link:**
addressInformation: {,…}
billing_address: {countryId: "IN", regionId: "615", regionCode: "IN-JH", region: "Jharkhand", street: ["test"],…}
city: "hyderbad"
countryId: "IN"
firstname: "test"
lastname: "hello"
postcode: "500001"
region: "Jharkhand"
regionCode: "IN-JH"
regionId: "615"
saveInAddressBook: null
street: ["test"]
telephone: "08096554505"
extension_attributes: {}

address: {street: ["test"], city: "hyderbad", region_id: "615", region: "Jharkhand", country_id: "IN",…}
city: "hyderbad"
country_id: "IN"
firstname: "test"
lastname: "hello"
postcode: "500001"
region: "Jharkhand"
region_id: "615"
save_in_address_book: 1
street: ["test"]
telephone: "08096554505"
```

I have added the below process to Edit link:

Below file contain some code for edit address:

> Magento\Customer\view\frontend\web\js\model\customer\address.js

```
getCacheKey: function() {
return this.getKey();
},
isEditable: function() {
return false;
},
canUseForBilling: function() {
return true;
}
```

in magento 2 given fixed value for edit: return false.

**but Here I have added the edit: return true. Edit link is working but selected address doesn't showing in popup**

I was observed my console Please check below :

```
addressInformation: {,…}
billing_address: {customerAddressId: "9047", countryId: "IN", regionId: "631", regionCode: "IN-TS", region: "Telangana",…}
city: "hyderabad"
countryId: "IN"
customAttributes: {zoylo_address_id: {attribute_code: "zoylo_address_id", value: ""},…}
customerAddressId: "9047"
customerId: "264691"
firstname: "test1"
lastname: "hello1"
postcode: "500070"
region: "Telangana"
regionCode: "IN-TS"
regionId: "631"
saveInAddressBook: null
street: ["test"]
telephone: "9152454343"
extension_attributes: {}



{"addressId":"9047"}
```